# Enum to int casting for array index

Tags: c#, enums

I am confused what I should do to make this work:

```
enum Phonemes { Phoneme0 = 0, Phoneme1 = 1, Phoneme2 = 2 };
enum Features { PhonemeID = 0, IsFirst = 1, IsLast = 2 };

        int[][] inputs = new int[3][];
        inputs[0] = new int[3];
        inputs[1] = new int[3];
        inputs[2] = new int[3];

        inputs[(int)Phonemes.Phoneme0][int()Features.PhonemeID] = 1;
```

The first enum to int works fine, but as soon as I add the [int()Features.PhonemeID], the compiler does not like it anymore.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Is the code above a real copy/paste? Because of course it would not compile, it must be `(int)` instead of `int()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
 inputs[(int)Phonemes.Phoneme0][(int)Features.PhonemeID] = 1;
```

your brackets were wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simple typo

Change it to this:

```
inputs[(int)Phonemes.Phoneme0][(int)Features.PhonemeID] = 1;
```

You have written `int()` instead of `(int)`

Comment: I fixed your typo too ;p And now you cancel it out!